# Is there any DAX expression for calculating SUM of few rows based on an index?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose I have the following data :

```
MachineNumber | Duration  
01 | 234
01 | 200
01 | 150 
02 | 320
02 | 120
02 | 100
```

I want to know a DAX query which can add 234 + 200 + 150 since it belongs to machine 01 and give me the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the Machine

like this table 
[image]

you have do avoid the automatic sum on your MachineNumber

[image: desactivate automatic sum]

You can also do a transformation in the PowerQuery editor by specifying that your MachineNumber is a string in place of a Number

Comment: I dont have to use the slicer actually.

Comment: My desired output is a a new table saying machine 1 takes 584 seconds and machine 2 takes 220 seconds

Comment: Ok a new table in data source from powerBi or in the report ?

Comment: A new table in the report.

Comment: I change the original response with new information that you gave

Answer (score 0):

To find the total duration machine wise, I chose SUM option from the field and machine wise total sum got displayed.